# CS50 pset-1 itsa Mario - make a half-pyramid using parameters from user input

Tags: beginner, c, programming-challenge, ascii-art

I'm taking Harvard's introduction to computer science (CS50) course online, and I've written a program that satisfies a coding challenge but I don't understand what I did or how I can improve it. I'm a very green programmer.

The challenge is to get an int from the user between 0 and 23 and use that to set the line height of a half-pyramid drawn in the terminal using hashes, ala the ramp at the ends of the levels in Super Mario Bros:

> ```
>    ##
>   ###
>  ####
> #####
> ```

After about 6 hours of banging my head against the wall I came up with the following:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int height;

    printf("How high do you want your half-pyramid?\n");
    height = GetInt();

     //verify that height is an int between 0 and 23

    while (height > 23 || height < 0) 

        {
            printf("Invalid entry:\nChoose a number between 0 and 23\n");
            height = GetInt();
        }

    // draw the pyramid

    for (int line = 0; line < height; line++)
      {
         // draw spaces
        for (int space = line + 2; space < height + 1; space++)
         {
         printf(" ");
         }

         // draw hashes
        for (int hash = line + height + 1; height < hash + 1; hash--)
        {
         printf("#");
        } 
        printf("\n");
      }

    return 0;
}
```

I understand the part that I've commented as "verify that height is an `int` between 0 and 23," but everything in the "draw the pyramid" section was arrived at by brute force. Just making one thing that kind of looked like it worked and then tweaking it over and over again until it did what I needed it to do. Maybe this is how everyone codes, but I hope not.

Can anyone give me some insight in fairly plain language about what the code here is doing, some ideas about how it might be improved, or just some other ways to go about it?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! At one time or another we have all had to "hack" some code until it worked, usually before knowing what the good techniques/methods are. I hope you get some good answers!

Answer (score 1):

#### Organized coding

A line of a pyramid is made by x spaces and y hashes. The number of spaces is given by the total line length minus the number of hashes. The number of hashes increases from 2 to 5, the max line length is 5

```
static int LINE_LEN = 5;
for (int hashes = 2; hashes <= LINE_LEN; hashes++) {
    print_repeated_char(' ', LINE_LEN - hashes);
    print_repeated_char('#', hashes);
    printf("\n");
 }
```

Also note the `print_repeated_char` function avoids repetition.

Comment: I've tried to rebuild the program substituting your code snippet but at compile I get this error:

 error: implicit declaration of function 'print_repeated_char' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Any ideas why? Is there a library I need to add?

Comment: @RobertE I meant  it was on You to write that function. Just use a for loop to call printf repeadately on the char.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you mean. This is my 3rd program. I tried to create a variable char print_repeated_char and got a different error: called object type 'char' is not a function or function pointer. If what you've written above is not the complete code for whatever it is you're explaining I don't know whatever it is that's needed to fill in the blanks.

Comment: @RobertE Google: "how to define functions in C++"

Comment: Ok i did that and read about 20 pages of info that made no sense to me.  Again, this is the third program I've written. The first was a "hello, world" and the second was one which takes a user input and multiplies it, returning the product. I honestly have no idea where you're trying to lead me with the above snippet. I can see what it's supposed to do, kind of, but how to implement it is beyond me.

Comment: @Caridorc I think at this point in the course, they have not covered writing functions (except `main`).

Comment: @luser droog They've touched on it but not enough for me to get over the hump on this problem. As far as I can figure I need to do the following:
`int print_repeated_char(char int)
{something in here that will be 
printf(XXXX);
}`

Comment: @RobertE I recommend that you ask over in [comp.lang.c](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/comp.lang.c). Then we (me and other readers there) can help without breaking the rules of StackExchange sites (like long discussions in comments).